# What SSL certificate to use with web app with API on Azure?

Tags: ssl, certificate, azure, web-applications

I am creating a web service / app and hosting it on Azure.
Users signing up for the service will get their own subdomain, e.g. user1.example.com.
I have an API which is accessible through www.
I want to secure communication with SSL for both the API and for browsing the different pages and sub domains.

I am unsure what type of SSL certificate to use and am looking for advice.

I have been looking at the wildcard certificate at [thawte](http://www.thawte.com/ssl/wildcard-ssl-certificates/index.html) but I'm not sure it's the right choice.

Comment: Do you need to secure multiple vhost in your domain? If so, then get the wildcard cert. Otherwise, just get a single "standard" certificate.

Comment: Sorry - this is a domain where I don't have a lot of knowledge. Wouldn't I need to get a wildcard certificate to secure both www. and user1., user2., user3. etc.?

Comment: Do the users (user1) get Server-Certificates? Are the users running their own web service? I guess not. Or are the users supposed to get client certificates, which they should use to authenticate to your API? Maybe you should reorganize your API, so that the users are accessing www.example.com/user1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As new users will get their their own sub-domain, **Wildcard SSL Certificate** is the perfect choice.

**Thawte Wildcard** Costs high compared with **Comodo** & **RapidSSL**'s wildcard SSLs. If price matters for you it will be better you go with Comodo or RapidSSL.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the situation you're describing, a Wildcard SSL would be the right choice for you. I personally use SSL.com, but there is nothing intrinsically wrong with thawte, it's just more expensive.